# How to prohibit access to a view if the user is not the user in the account path?

Tags: views, 8

I created a page view to display forms created by the user on his account.

I added a "Submitted by" context filter to this view to filter the user ID of the logged in user.

My problem :

When I disconnect and reload the page, the view is still displayed. How to prevent access to this page if the user does not match the user of the account path ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The submitted by is not an access will not do it

I will post all the steps below since I am not sure what you have done (your view is translated in french)

Basically you will have a view of `webform submissions` with `relationship to the user` and `filter the current user`

#### creating the view

[image: webform submissions view]

#### adding the user relationship

[image: adding the user relationship]

#### adding the current user filter

[image]

#### the finished view with important parts highlighted

[image: webform submissions view]

the current logged in user should see ONLY their submissions NOW